# Regex for matching document ID numbers in free-form text

Tags: regex

I have to match document ID's in free-form text. The text is already split into sentences or lines and there is at most one ID number in each line. The ID's can have different formats and can include spaces, so in general I want to match:

- a word indicating that an ID follows (let's assume it's always "ID")
- some whitespace/punctuation (let's assume it's either at least one space or exactly one colon surrounded with optional spaces)
- any sequence of letters, digits, slashes and hyphens, optionally containing spaces, but (and now's the catch) **there's no sequence "digit-space-letter" in it** (because usually this means that the letter belongs to a word that follows the ID; a sequence "letter-space-letter" is ambiguous, but usually happens inside an ID, so I want it to match)

So for example, I want to match:

```
ID: 1
ID 1/1
ID : 1/A
ID     AAA X1
ID :B/B
ID 1/ A
ID 1 /A
ID 1 /A/ AA
ID 1 /A /AA
ID AA 123
ID AA 123 123
ID AA/123 123
```

but not

```
ID 1 AAA
ID 1/1 AAA
```

In the above two cases, I want to match only `ID 1` and `ID 1/1` respectively.

This is what I got so far, it doesn't work though:

`ID(\s+|\s*:\s*)(?:[\p{L}0-9/-]*\s)*[0-9/-][\p{L}0-9/-]*`

Comment: Should `ID 1/1 AAA` be matched ? It has the `1 A` part which is "digit-space-letter".

Comment: @Theox: Oops, my bad, you're right.

Comment: On your lines, do you have only the ID? Meaning, in `ID 1 AAA` do you want to match `ID 1` or nothing at all?

Comment: I want to match `ID 1`. The words that may follow a digit should be ignored.

Comment: What language are you using? It can be useful to know if lookbehind can be used.

Comment: @Robin: Java, but I'd prefer to avoid lookbehinds due to performance. Besides, I think I solved it already.

Answer (score 0):

The regex:

```
ID(?: *: *| +)(?:(?!\d\s+[a-zA-Z])[\da-zA-Z/\s])*\d?
```

might do the trick.

`ID(?: *: *| +)` matches `ID` followed by a combination of spaces and `:` (max one `:`). Afterward we're onto the good parts, and the regex engine will try to match characters one by one:
`(?!\d\s+[a-zA-Z])` checks that we are not on a digit followed by a space and a letter. If we are, we stop, and we catch this last digit with the final `\d?`. If we're not, this means we can match the character with `[\da-zA-Z/\s]`. We then pass on the following character and perform the same check, until we reach the end of line or a special character.

Comment: I clarified that I need to extract the ID even if followed by words that are not a part of that ID.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, thanks to hints I finally figured it out on my own:

```
ID(?: +| *: *)((?:[0-9](?:\s+(?![a-zA-Z]))?|[A-Za-z/]\s*)*)
```

After every non-blank character, I attempt to match spaces, but after a digit I match optional spaces under a condition that those spaces are not followed by a letter.

Comment: `(?: | *: *)+` can be simplified with `[ :]+`, if you want to also match `ID` followed by multiple spaces.

Comment: Not if you want it to match only one colon.

Comment: I ran it through http://regex101.com/ and there it did not seem to match `ID 1` out of `ID 1 AAA` and the other one, but that may be due to the site, I've had it do weird stuff on complicated regular expressions more often. Remember to escape forward slashes if you use it, it's javascript flavour based.

Comment: @Bart: Good point. But `(?: | *: *)+` also matches multiple colons. Something like `(?: *: *| +)`?

Comment: @Robin: Right, I fixed it.

Comment: @KarolS: be careful, you're not matching `ID :` anymore. On `(?: +| *: *)` the regex engine matches `(?: +)` first, so it matches `ID `. Then you're on `:` and you try to match it with `((?:[0-9](?:\s+(?![a-zA-Z]))?|[A-Za-z/]\s*)*)` so it obviously stops. Order is important here, you should use `(?: *: *| +)` (or have a look at the updated answers)

Answer (score -1):

Here's my edited solution :

You can use two regexs :

First :

```
ID[\s:]+[\da-zA-Z\s/-]*
```

It matches `ID` followed by spaces or comas, with at least one of these.

Then the `[\da-zA-Z\s/-]*` part will match any sequence of digits, letters, spaces, slashes and hyphens.

This will make sure your setence follows the wanted pattern.

The additional condition is done with a second regex :

```
\d [a-zA-Z]
```

If this second regex is matched, then your sentence doesn't respect the no sequence "digit-space-letter" condition, and should be rejected.

Comment: I don't think this will work, since it will only check the negative lookahead directly after the spaces/colons. If you have one character followed by the digit/space/character "break" condition it's still going to match those characters.

Comment: @BartEnkelaar I agree, the lookahead doesn't work. I'm trying to find how to make the lookahead global. How about using two different regexs ?

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question as OP doesn't want to discard completely the line when encountering `1 A` pattern. FYI you can do what you suggest in only one regex: `(?!.*\d [a-zA-Z])ID[\s:]+[\da-zA-Z\s/-]*`